# facing problem in rasa init function in anaconda prompt

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, rasa

```
import regex
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'regex'

import regex error
i already have installed by command "pip install rasa" but still facing problem

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re # re == RegExr == regex
regex_find = r'\w' # r-string == 'regex code'
```

docs: [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)